# Why can I create a plot using df.plot, but then modify the plot I see by calling the plt object?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Maybe I'm just missing something really straightforward here. But I know in pandas I can use the matplotlib plotting feature by simply doing `dataframe.plot` ([info here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)).

But how is it that I can modify that EXACT plot by just using `plt.title`, `plt.xlabel`, `plt.ylabel`, etc.? it doesn't make sense to me. For reference, I'm following [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-beginners-guide-to-linear-regression-in-python-with-scikit-learn-83a8f7ae2b4f)

```
dataset.plot(x='MinTemp', y='MaxTemp', style='o')  
plt.title('MinTemp vs MaxTemp')  
plt.xlabel('MinTemp')  
plt.ylabel('MaxTemp')  
plt.show()
```

Does it have something to do with the fact that when I'm running `.plot` on a dataframe, I'm really creating a `matplotlib.pyplot` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib has the concept of the *current axes*. Essentially what this means is that whenever you first do something that requires an `axes` object, one is created for you and becomes the default object that all of your future actions will be applied to until you change the current axes to something else. In your case, `dataset.plot(x='MinTemp', y='MaxTemp', style='o')` creates an `axes` object and sets it as the current axes. All of `plt.title()`, `plt.xlabel()`, and `plt.ylabel()` simply apply their changes to the current axes.

Comment: thanks so much. you nailed the answer for me and made it crystal clear.