# Why isn't plt.figure(figsize=(X,y)) changing the size on my .hist and .plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm getting a bit confused around the concepts of axes, and frankly - what modifies what when it comes to the matplotlib backend. I was told in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59779685/why-can-i-create-a-plot-using-df-plot-but-then-modify-the-plot-i-see-by-calling/59779741#59779741) that **"whenever you first do something that requires an axes object, one is created for you and becomes the default object that all of your future actions will be applied to until you change the current axes to something else."**

But why is it, then, that figsize doesn't seem to do anything when I use the following code in the same cells in a Jupyter notebook:

```
dataset[['TV','radio']].plot()
plt.figure(figsize=(5,10))
```

and also

```
dataset.hist()
plt.figure(figsize=(10,20))
```

Why don't either of these work? How can I tell which axes object I'm referencing? Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `plt.figure` creates a new figure.

If you want to resize the existing figure use this:

```
dataset[['TV','radio']].plot()
fig = plt.gcf() # gcf: get current figure
fig.set_size_inches(5,10)
```

---

Another way you could do it -- that's illustrative of how axes get created and later used -- is to start off with the figure size like this:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[np.random.randint(0,10) for i in range(10)]}) 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = fig.gca() # gca: get current axes
df.plot(ax=ax)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! But why doesnt this work: 

dataset[['TV','radio']].plot()
and

plt.set_size_inches(10,10)

Comment: `plt` is the plotting module and does not have the `.set_size_inches()` method. It provides basic plotting tools, but for anything more complicated you've got to use the object-oriented API which is what you're doing with `fig = plt.figure()`

Comment: really appreciate your time and effort @bernie!